# Why is wysihtml5 not loading in my textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wysihtml5

The script is working just fine for the textarea in the body of the page. However, it doesn't work at the textarea created dynamically by Javascript. As follow I have enclosed the script. The PHP inc/toolbar.php includes the toolbar of the editable textarea. How can I add the visual editor in those all textareas? This is part of newsletter CMS I am developing. I just want to get the editor embed in the textarea. I have uploaded the demo here http://benchmarkinc.com.au/test/. Please anyone help to sort this issue. I am quite sure that this http://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/ tutorial is exactly showing about the same issue I am facing. However, I couldn't relate in my problem.

```
  <script>

  //Case summary
    var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("case_summary",{
    toolbar:      "toolbar2",
    stylesheets:  "css/wyiswyg.css",
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
  });

          var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("casesum",{
    toolbar:      "toolbar3",
    stylesheets:  "css/wyiswyg.css",
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
  });

</script>


<textarea class="form-control" name="case_summary[]" id="case_summary" rows="20"></textarea>


function addRow(frm) {
    caseNum ++;
    var row = '<div class="form-group"><label>Summary: </label><textarea class="form-control" name="case_summary[]" rows="20" id="casesum"></textarea> </div> <div class="form-group"></label></div><div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertme">Please select at least one editon</div>    <div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeRow('+caseNum+');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> remove...</button></div><hr />   </div>';
    jQuery('#caseAdd').append(row);
    document.getElementById("case_title").value = document.case_title.value;
    document.getElementById("case_summary").value = document.case_summary.value;
}
```

Comment: Attach the editor after adding the element ..

Comment: Hi, Syed. Yes that is good idea as my dynamic form is loading after the editor. But, how can i load the editor after the Javascript dynamic form?

Comment: I have uploaded the demo here: http://benchmarkinc.com.au/test/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with Syed solution but it didn't work. I tweaked it a bit adding just a function to the wysihtml5 editor and it worked fine. So here is the final code looks like. Though it doesn't make sense why it worked that way. Thank you guys for help.

```
function addRow(frm) {
    caseNum ++;
    var row = '<div class="form-group"><label>Summary: </label><textarea class="form-control" name="case_summary[]" rows="20" id="casesum"></textarea> </div> <div class="form-group"></label></div><div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertme">Please select at least one editon</div>    <div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeRow('+caseNum+');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> remove...</button></div><hr />   </div>';
    jQuery('#caseAdd').append(row);
    document.getElementById("case_title").value = document.case_title.value;
    document.getElementById("case_summary").value = document.case_summary.value;

   callEventHandler(); //function call
}

function callEventHandler()
{
var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("casesum",{
    toolbar:      "toolbar3",
    stylesheets:  "css/wyiswyg.css",
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach will be to add your `wysihtml5` handler in your `addRow` function, after appending the element in the body.

```
function addRow(frm) {
    caseNum ++;
    var row = '<div class="form-group"><label>Summary: </label><textarea class="form-control" name="case_summary[]" rows="20" id="casesum"></textarea> </div> <div class="form-group"></label></div><div class="alert alert-danger" id="alertme">Please select at least one editon</div>    <div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="removeRow('+caseNum+');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> remove...</button></div><hr />   </div>';
    jQuery('#caseAdd').append(row);
    document.getElementById("case_title").value = document.case_title.value;
    document.getElementById("case_summary").value = document.case_summary.value;

    var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("casesum",{
      toolbar:      "toolbar3",
      stylesheets:  "css/wyiswyg.css",
      parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
    });
}
```

Comment: Syed, that seems too not working. I have uploaded the demo here. Can you look into this please. http://benchmarkinc.com.au/test/

Comment: This tutorial might help to fix: http://toddmotto.com/attaching-event-handlers-to-dynamically-created-javascript-elements/

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code with jQuery ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
//Case summary
    var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("case_summary",{
    toolbar:      "toolbar2",
    stylesheets:  "css/wyiswyg.css",
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
  });

          var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor("casesum",{
    toolbar:      "toolbar3",
    stylesheets:  "css/wyiswyg.css",
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cevek, but unfortunately it didn't work though. I wrapped around the code with jQuery ready function. I am thinking of switching editor. Do you recommend any of them?

Comment: Thanks Cevek, but I am looking for some free scripts :-)